# How to create loop for verification of status from http endpoint in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-requests, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have to create a verification of GitLab pipeline.
I trigger pipeline, get its ID and then checking status of that specific pipeline.
Requesting GitLab API Pipeline endpoint I'm getting some stages - "pending", "running" and afterwards "success" or "failed".
I'm beginner with python.
How can I retry that API call using python requests and get result only as "success" or "failed" ?
I do have:

```
triggered_pipeline_id = "7532"
url = "{0}{1}".format(pipelineurl, triggered_pipeline_id)
response = requests.get(url=url, verify=False, headers=apidata)
raw_content = response.content.decode('UTF-8')
json_output = json.loads(raw_content)
returned_id = str(json_output["id"])
returned_status = str(json_output["status"])
```

This will give me immediately status - but it's "pending" or "running". After few seconds it has "success" or "failed". But rather than sleep for few seconds I guess it would be better to retry until response is "success" or "failed".

I thought that "while" loop would be best - but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I have this in mind :

```
while (( returned_status == "pending" ) || ( returned_status == "running" )):
    time.sleep(5)
```

Is that correct or what should I do ?
Thank you for your hints in advance :)

Comment: `while (( returned_status == "pending" ) or ( returned_status == "running" )): ...`

Comment: Alternatively, `while returned_status in ("pending", "running"): ...`

Comment: Hi @JustinEzequiel so what does that mean? What I wrote should do the magic ? :) I mean if I put time.sleep(5) there it will retry after 5 seconds and if status is not "pending" or "running" it will continue?

Comment: What I meant with my comments was just that `||` does not do what you expected it to do. This is python and not JAVA or C#. I haven't bothered to check the other parts of your code which is why I have not posted an answer.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the rest of your code is working...

```py
response = requests.get(url=url, verify=False, headers=apidata)
json_output = response.json()
returned_status = json_output["status"]

while returned_status in ("pending", "running"):
    time.sleep(5)

    # repeat the request
    response = requests.get(url=url, verify=False, headers=apidata)
    json_output = response.json()
    returned_status = json_output["status"]
    
# continue with the rest of your code
print(returned_status)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @JustinEzequiel you made my day :)